# Java Regex: Finding double quotes and noticing escape chracters

Tags: java, regex

I am having trouble making a regex that notices escape characters inside of quotes.

For example, *Two "quoted strings" in "this line"* would return:

> quoted strings
>
> this line

*This string "contains an \" escaped quote mark".* would return:

> contains an \" escaped quote mark

I made a regex to match quotes

```
\\\"[^\\\"\\n]*\\\"
```

- \\" quote
- [^\\"\n]* anything but a quote or new line
- \\" quote

How would I make a regex that ignores escape characters inside of the quotes?

**Note:** I only want the escape characters to be noticed inside of the quotes, so something like *This is \"a dog"* should still output *a dog*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(?:\\\\\"|[^\"])*\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher("\"contains an \\\" escaped quote mark\"");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```